# Django form override FloatField max_value attribute

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm trying override the **"max_value"** attribute in the child class without success. What I'm doing wrong?

**Parent Class**

```
class ParentForm(forms.Form):

    width = forms.FloatField(label='Width (B)', max_value=100, min_value=5)
    # others fields
```

**Child Class**

```
class ChildForm(ParentForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['width'].max_value = 50
```

Comment: It should work. Add your view code and exception if there is one. What version of django and python you are using?

Comment: I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6. This code works well with the **"label"** attribute for example, but not with **"max_value"** and **"min_value"**.

Comment: You think that it isn't working because it doesn't fail on validation?

Comment: The **max_value** that is using for validation is the value from the parent class. The overriding is not working with this new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `max_value` is set correctly, the issue is that you don't update validator

In `__init__` of `IntegerField` which is parent of `FloatField` it does this

```
def __init__(self, max_value=None, min_value=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.max_value, self.min_value = max_value, min_value
        if kwargs.get('localize') and self.widget == NumberInput:
            # Localized number input is not well supported on most browsers
            kwargs.setdefault('widget', super(IntegerField, self).widget)
        super(IntegerField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if max_value is not None:
            self.validators.append(validators.MaxValueValidator(max_value))
        if min_value is not None:
            self.validators.append(validators.MinValueValidator(min_value))
```

So for fully updating `max_value` and `min_value` you need also update validators, here is one approach

```
from django.core import validators

class ChildForm(ParentForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        max_value = 50
        self.fields['width'].max_value = max_value
        for validator in self.fields['width'].validators:
            if isinstance(validator, validators.MaxValueValidator):
                validator.limit_value = max_value
```

Comment: I'm getting an exception. _'ChildForm' object has no attribute 'validators'._ I think this is a improve. I'll work on it.

Comment: @Eduardo Yeah, should be `self.fields['width'].validators` fixed my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Pass class name and self in super

```
class ChildForm(ParentForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ChildForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['width'].max_value = 50
```

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6. I don't need those arguments.